# SQL Server database replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

I am working on a db optimization (planing for future project growth) and need some help.

Currently, every table is using a `uniqueidentifier` column as PK (clustered index) and we have high index fragmentation (99%). For the new tables we started using `bigint` as pk but I don't want a nightmare when bidirectional replication phase comes.

I did my research and `uniqueidentifier` is not a huge problem (except memory), problem is clustered index on that column (http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/).

Can we do this to solve our fragmentation problem and any replication nightmare:

1. Add a `ROWGUIDCOL` to PK column
2. Add another `identity` column in every table and move that clustered index (not pk) to that column

Would this new identity column cause the same replication problems as if that was `bigint` PK?

I know SharePoint database primary keys are GUIDs but I am not happy with its performances and probably security has some part in that decision.

We could reduce fragmentation by using seq. GUIDs but we can't create it on application side or return it with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. `OUTPUT inserted.ID` hack would be time consuming because we need to rewrite complete application DAL.

Finally, is there any valid solution for this problem? Can we use `bigint` without any replication problem?

Thanks

Comment: Probably better suited for the [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you seeing that says that bigint and p2p replication are incompatible?

Comment: To use identity columns in a replication topology that has updates at more than one node, each node in the replication topology must use a different range of identity values, so that duplicates do not occur. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152543.aspx